# How to get a php value from a select option?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the value of $animal when I select an option so I can press the button and see detailed info of this option.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJw0d.png)

```
@foreach ($animais as $animal)

  <option value="{{ $animal->id }}">{{ $animal->nome }}</option>
@endforeach
  </select>
  
  <a href="{{ route("animals.show", $animal) }}"><button type="submit">Ver</button></a>
```

Comment: You could use a modal box, inside the modal box you could call function that pulls data from a data base to display.

Comment: FYI: You can not nest `button` into `a`, that is invalid HTML.

Comment: @CBroe how would you recommend me? i'm kinda newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One the HTML page is written from the PHP, that value is a node in the DOM, and you can access it through javascript.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('select.example').addEventListener('change', e => {
    console.log('value selected: ', e.target.value, 'from text', e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text)
  })
})
```

```html
<select class='example'>
  <option value='zebra'>animal</option>
  <option value='carrot'>vegetable</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! It was exactly what I wanted.